# Spring Boot .war in Tomcat - Can I use an external properties file?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I have packaged my Spring Boot app as a .war file, and it is running in Tomcat 7 under file path /opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war.

However, I would like to use properties from a file in /var/{filePath}/application.properties where filePath is as yet unknown. I have read the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and I suspect the best way would be using a JNDI attribute.

I have configured a resource in context.xml as follows:

```
<Resource auth="Container" type="java.lang.String" name="myProperties" url="/var/myDirectory/application.properties"/>
```

Is this correct?

And if so, how can I inject these properties into my Spring Boot app, considering it is a .war?

Comment: Which properties? The JNDI ones or the ones from the properties file?

Comment: @M.Deinum the ones from the properties file :)

Comment: Just add an `@PropertySource` to your configuration class. Which points to `file:/var/{filePath}/application.properties`. Or simply use the `spring.config.location` property and register that in JNDI (or SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION` and that will be automatically used by Spring Boot to detect the `application.properties`).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question :)

I added the following to my Tomcat context.xml:

```
<Parameter name="agent-tools-api.properties" value="/var/zoona/agent-tools-api.properties" />
```

And added a corresponding @PropertySources annotation onto Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources(@PropertySource(value = {"file:${agent-tools-api.properties}"}))
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   // Application class
}
```

So it gets the property file path *from* another property. A bit convoluted, but it works.

Comments welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I've used something like this in tomcat's catalina.sh as environment variable and spring is able to detect that.

export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=/krishna/software/repository/conf/trimble/application.properties